# git rebase orphan branch and delete missing files

Tags: git

I've checked out an orphan branch and am applying it to a branch with an unrelated history.  This works great except for one scenario--deletions.  If the source branch deletes a tracked file, the deletion does not carry over to the target branch when I apply the orphan branch.

```
git switch sourceBranch
git checkout --orphan orphanBranch
git rebase -X theirs otherRemote/targetBranch
```

As I said, this works fine until a tracked file is deleted from `sourceBranch`.  The deletion doesn't get applied to `targetBranch`.  Is there a way to have files that are missing from a snapshot be deleted?

(note: I'm rebasing to avoid the merge commit.  Since these are unrelated histories, it won't ever FF.)

Comment: Once you've "disconnected" the new orphan branch (made a root commit in it), there's no "deletion" event: it just has the snapshot it has. However, the sequence above sets you up with on a new branch named `orphanBranch` that does not yet exist: you have not yet made the initial commit. Running `git rebase` will put you into detached HEAD mode on this orphan branch that still does not exist, which may cause oddities. It might be wise to `git commit` first, so that you create it so that it can be rebased. But that might interfere with what you're *really* trying to do (which I can't quite get).

Comment: (Please excuse me while I have a fanboy moment--thank you for all your detailed, high-quality git answers!) I'm modifying a preexisting process that was to manually copy a subset of a repo to "publish" to another repo. I of course paraphrased what I'm actually doing and after checking out the orphan branch I am, in fact, committing. I had kinda worked out that the deletion "event" wouldn't be seen since there was only the single snapshot. That makes sense. I was hoping for a bit of git magic to say "make the snapshot be only what you see here" or "replace the previous snapshot with this one".

Comment: To completely replace a snapshot, use [`git read-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree). As plumbing commands go, this one's fairly tricky: add `-u` if you want the current working tree updated, and then you'll need one of `--reset`, `-m`, or `--prefix` to completely replace the current index. Despite the description of `-m` it doesn't actually mean *merge the current index* (this confused me for a long time so that I always used `--reset`: not harmful in most cases, but definitely tricky).

Comment: Finally had the chance to put this to use during our release and it works like a charm.  If you want to write up an answer, I'll gladly accept it. @torek

Comment: At this point, I've forgotten the original question, and have way too much other stuff to do anyway - you might want to provide a self-answer with the exact setup....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a preexisting process that involved manually preparing a subset of a private repo to be copied over to a public repo.  The preparation process was pretty straightforward, so I wanted to automated it.  The process described in the original question worked fine unless a tracked file was deleted.  Since I was removing all history (with `--orphan`) there was no way for the deletion to be applied to the public repo.

@torek's suggestion of using `git read-tree` worked perfectly.  It allowed me to create the desired snapshot for the public repo and apply it as-is.

```bash
# starting point
git switch sourceBranch
# detach from history; this is going to a different repo with unrelated history
git checkout --orphan orphanBranch
# get repo ready to publish to public repo and then commit
git commit -m "Release ready"
# create new branch off of the other repo's master
git checkout -b releaseBranch public-remote/master
# create the snapshot from the prepared orphan branch
git read-tree -mu orphanBranch
# success!
git commit -m "Release"
git push public-remote releaseBranch:releaseBranch
```